# I/O Error with uploadify in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uploadify

I'm trying to upload a image using uploadify and paperclip on rail 3.0.9

When i upload a image with uploadify, the server returns an I/O error. The development.log says:

```
Started POST "/user/albums" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-09 09:07:15 -0800
  Processing by User::AlbumsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"Filename"=>"slogon.png", "_http_accept"=>"application/javascript", "folder"=>"/user/dashboard/signup/", "user_id"=>"1", "Filedata"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa20907c @original_filename="slogon.png", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"slogon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120109-3021-1q66icv>>, "Upload"=>"Submit Query"}
```

Completed   in 3ms

This is my controller:

```
def create
    newparams = coerce(params)
    @album = Album.new(newparams[:album])
    if @album.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created upload."
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @album.user}
        format.json {render :json => { :result => 'success', :upload =>   album_path(@album) } }
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

 private 
  def coerce(params)
    if params[:album].nil? 
      h = Hash.new 
      h[:album] = Hash.new 
      h[:album][:user_id] = params[:user_id]
      h[:album][:photo] = params[:Filedata] 
      h[:album][:photo].content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(h[:album[:photo].original_filename).to_s
      h
    else 
      params
    end 
  end
```

And this is my uploader:

```
<script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "swfobject.js", "jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js" %>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#album_photo').click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
    }); 

    jQuery('#album_photo').uploadify({
    uploader : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        cancelImg : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
        multi : true,
        auto : true,
    script : '/user/albums',
        onComplete : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { 
            var dat = eval('(' + response + ')');
            jQuery.getScript(dat.upload);},
    scriptData : {
            '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
                    'format' : 'json',
            '_method': 'post',
            'user_id' : '<%= @user.id %>'
          }
    });

    jQuery('#album_photo').click(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            jQuery('#album_photo').uploadifyUpload(); 
        });

 }); 
 </script>
<h3>Upload a Photo</h3> 
<%= form_for Album.new(:user_id => @user.id), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
<p>
<%= f.file_field :photo %> </p>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: can we see the full error please? I/O errors with uploads are usually to do with space in the /tmp dir in my experience. run "df -h" on the server and check that there's plenty of space available (if /tmp is listed as a separate item then it has limited space and is therefore probably saved to memory or something).

Comment: thanks for reply but I have solve the issue. Actually js getting a problem.

Comment: @Amol It might be worth putting the solution in and answering your own question. Others can learn from it then.